# ACTION_SEND intent android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

I am trying to pass a url to a specific app using the ACTION_SEND intent, I want to by pass the chooser and just go straight to the app i desire but it doesn't seem to take the url unless i use the chooser..

```
    private void shareIt(){

                Intent pC = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                pC.setType("text/plain");
                pC.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "http://www.bob.com");
                pC.setType("text/plain");
                pC.setClassName("com.sec.print.mobileprint","com.sec.print.mobileprint.UI.WebPrint");
                //startActivity(pC);

                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(pC,"Share jon"));

            }
```

if i comment out the last line and comment back in the line before it.. it opens the app i want bypassing the chooser,  but the app opens to google instead of bob.com..  if i leave it as is.. it brings up the chooser and should i choose the app it goes to bob.com ..  how can i get it to go to bob.com while bypassing the chooser?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the [Intent.setClassName](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setClassName%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method you’re calling takes an *unqualified* class name as its second argument (after all, why bother repeating the package name qualification?). Alternatively, you can use [setClass](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setClass%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.Class%3C?%3E%29) instead.

Comment: I thought setClass was only good for class files inherent to your app.
ie:
        Intent.setClass(this,"myClass.class");

I am using a third party app as my intent.. could you clarify how i would write that?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you need to pass the URL via EXTRA_TEXT and not by `pC.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.bob.com");`?

Comment: I actually tried that first, yuku.. but thanks.. i am running in circles right now.